# Sim Controller not opening when testing app on desktop Flash Pro CS6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs6

I am publishing an app on AIR for Android 3.2 in Flash Pro CS6. Everything was working fine, but then all of the sudden the Sim Controller stopped coming up when I test my movie.

The app makes pretty heavy use of the swipe feature, and without the sim controller I have to debug-publish to my phone every time which is quite annoying.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Please be sure to tag your questions directly.  This appears to have no relation to Flex.

Comment: Does your sim controller work in other movies? Just in case it broke.

Comment: @ flextras - directly or correctly? @ Vesper- It doesnt open for any movies anymore :(

Comment: update: the sim controller works fine for other projects, but still is nowhere to be found when testing that particular fla

Comment: Same problem,publish new movie no problem, current movie sim controller missing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found my solution to this problem, got to Control->Test Movie and make sure "In AIR Debug Launcher (Mobile)" is selected, I remember I messed around with publishing to test on a device and didn't change it back!

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that the Sim Controller did not start at all. Even for new project or when I reopened the Flash.

Solution was to close all Adobe related processes in Task Manager. Seemed that Adobe updater or something was interfering with opening AIR.

Restarting your computer should also solve this problem by closing all the updater and such.

Answer (score 0):

This is a project related problem. To fix it go to : Control / Clear Publish Cache and Test Movie